# How to Import NDK library to Eclipse

Tags: android, android-ndk

How do one import an Android NDK library into Eclipse Java project?
There is supposed to be some importer which does this, but I am unable to find the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can import an NDK project in to your Eclipse SDK project. On your project do a right-click and chose -> Android Tools -> Add Native Support -> Click Finish. This will pull your native project files to Eclipse. Now you have to implement the functions as given in several sample projects

Comment: ""You can import an NDK project in to your Eclipse SDK project."" I have a NDK project that doesn't detect by Eclipse: Import > Android[Existing Android Code Into Workspace]